# .PO file is found but I don't see translations: how to debug the problem?

Tags: themes, theme-options, localization, debug, testing

I have installed the [Stack theme](https://themeforest.net/item/stack-multipurpose-wordpress-theme-with-variant-page-builder/19707359), and I want to make Danish translations. I have downloaded the `Stack.pot` file, made the modifications I need, and uploaded them to:

```
/wp-content/themes/stack/languages/stack-da_DK.po
```

I installed a `PO/MO Editor` plugin, and here I can see my translation:

[image]

However, when I see the pages, it does not show my new changes.

**My question is, therefore:**

How do debug a problem such as this? Do I write some log in the theme directly (and how?)?

And is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the .MO file compiled saving the .PO file which is used by WordPress. Without .MO no traduction will be available.
You can use another plugin to translate your theme : Loco for example ; or a Windows software : Poedit, which will create a .MO file when you'll save your .PO file with your translation.

Comment: Nice point! I just tried to upload it, but doesn't show. What is the correct way to name it? `/stack-da_DK.mo`, `da_DK.mo` or `stack_da_DK.mo`? :-)

Comment: normally, saving your .po files you should have a .mo file with the same name. You should use another tool to translate your plugin easily, use loco translate it does all this stuff automatically but store in the translation in the wp-content/languages folder instead of the theme/language folder.